# How to configure L2TP/IPsec VPN on Ubuntu 18.04 gui?

Tags: networking, gnome, vpn

I am trying to make L2TP/IPsec VPN available in GUI on network settings on ubuntu 18.04 but with no luck. I tried the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-l2tp is already the newest version (1.2.8-2build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  network-manager-l2tp-gnome
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.
Need to get 24,7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 147 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 network-manager-l2tp-gnome amd64 1.2.8-2build1 [24,7 kB]
Fetched 24,7 kB in 0s (217 kB/s)                
Selecting previously unselected package network-manager-l2tp-gnome.
(Reading database ... 246523 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../network-manager-l2tp-gnome_1.2.8-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking network-manager-l2tp-gnome (1.2.8-2build1) ...
Setting up network-maniager-l2tp-gnome (1.2.8-2build1) ...
```

but with no luck. What am I missing on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears I configured everything correctly as it started working after I logged out of the user and logged back in.

Comment: @NitescuLucian Did this resolve your problem?

Comment: yes with a re-login

Comment: **@MrShunz and reviewers:** This is OP’s answer to his own problem. Don’t delete this answer, rather close the question.